# Unable to get active session from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Iam getting login url again and again from the following code.

```
    $this->fb = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $this->CI->config->item('facebook_app_id'),
        'secret' => $this->CI->config->item('facebook_secret'),
        'cookie' => true,
    ));

    if (!$this->fb->getSession()){

        echo $this->fb->getLoginUrl();
    }
```

When I print fb object, it shows valid api keys and secret key.

I have tried after cleaning cookies from Firefox. I also tried to exlusively logout and then relogin from the facebook account in very next tab of firefox. But result is same.

Above code is always generating the login url.

One more thing I noticed that, user just login and returns. There is no appliaction  approval message/screeen is displayed. Is there any problem with in the settings of my appliaction on facebook?

Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I like to use JS SDK along with the PHP SDK to get extra functionality.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId   : '<?php echo $this->appId ?>',
      session : <?php echo json_encode($this->fb->getSession()); ?>, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
      status  : true, // check login status
      cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

Then, assign this function to any link or button that you want to open the login and permission dialog (i'm using jQuery and a link with .fbConnect class for the example):

```
$(".fbConnect").click(function() {
          FB.login(function(response) {
            window.location.reload();
          }, {perms: 'user_photos,user_photo_video_tags,email,publish_stream'});
        });
```

Notice that the permissions are specified in the perms object. When it reloads, the session should be available to your PHP SDK.

Also make sure that you are working on the same URL that you have specified into your app configuration, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You will only get a valid session if the user account allows your application to connect.

Have you done that yet? The easiest way is to use the [login button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) provided by Facebook.